Why tomcat thread always above 80 while run the Springboot WAR?
I deployed my Spring Boot application on Tomcat. At first, it used only 10 threads, but from the next morning onwards, even during idle times, it was using more than 88 threads. I monitored this using the Tomcat manager. I don't know what to do—could the issue be with the application or Tomcat?
I have set a 3-minute timeout for external API calls, and I have closed the closeable objects and streams.
Can anyone tell me if the problem is in my application? If yes, what should I do in the controller, service, and repository layers?
